# Generic procedure to delete duplicates - no PKs

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I wrote a stored procedure with a table name as parameter, that checks if there are duplicate rows in this table. The statements are built dynamically of course:

```
INSERT INTO tmpTable
SELECT col1, col2,... FROM table GROUP BY col1, col2, ... HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

DELETE FROM tablename FROM tablenname 
INNER JOIN tmpTable ON ISNULL(tablename.col1, 0) = ISNULL(tmpTable.col1, 0)
AND ISNULL(tablename.col2, 0) = ISNULL(tmpTable.col2, 0)
AND ...;

INSERT INTO tablename SELECT * FROM tmpTable;
```

Should work so far, but problem is, that it fails when the table has blob columns, like text. Those can not be compared in the `JOIN`. I also tried

```
DELETE FROM tablename GROUP BY col1, col2, ... HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

but `GROUP BY` is not supported in `DELETE` statement directly without self-joining.

Also it's not possible to query <kbd>information_schema</kbd> for primary key of this table, since none of these tables has one.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the statement is already built dynamically, add casting the relevant columns to `varchar(max)` for the purpose of join. It's not difficult to figure which columns that are:

```
select c.name, quotename(c.name, '[')
from
  sys.columns c
  inner join sys.types t on c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
where
  c.object_id = object_id(@TABLE_NAME)
  and c.is_computed = 0
  and t.name in ('text', 'image', 'timestamp', 'xml')
```